# joinTable not updating

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-many

I am working on a Spring / hibernate project and facing issue with a @ManyToMany condition.
The join table spot_topo is created on loading the app along with the fields spots_id and topos_id but the insertions won't work(no error, just nothing inserted).
I tried adding @JoinTable but then it fails on compilation.
Any idea what can be setup wrong?
Thanks!

Spot Entity

```
@ManyToMany( fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
```

private List topos;

Topo Entity

```
@ManyToMany(
        mappedBy = "topos", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Spot> spots = new ArrayList<>();
```

Hibernate Config

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("org.example.demo.climb.consumer");
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("org.example.demo.climb.model");
   /* sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("org.example.demo.climb.webapp");*/
    Properties hProperties = hibernateProperties();
    hProperties.setProperty("show_sql", "true");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hProperties);
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/ClimbingWorld");
    dataSource.setUsername("ocp");
    dataSource.setPassword("123");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect");

    hibernateProperties.setProperty("show_sql", "true");
    return hibernateProperties;
}
```

When I try adding:

```
@ManyToMany( fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinTable(name = "spot_topo",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "topos_id",
                nullable = false, updatable = true) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "spots_id",
                nullable = false, updatable = true) })
private List<Topo> topos;
```

I am getting a compilation error:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'loginAction': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'memberManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'memberManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'memberDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'memberDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in org.example.demo.climb.consumer.config.HibernateConf: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

dependencies(Beans)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    4.0.0

```
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Informations du projet -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- ===== Projet Parent Maven ===== -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.example.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>climb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <spring.version>4.3.11.RELEASE</spring.version>

</properties>

<!-- ===== Informations Maven ===== -->
<artifactId>climb-model</artifactId>

<!-- ===== Informations générales ===== -->
<name>${projectName} - Model</name>


<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Dépendances -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- ===== Bibliothèques tierces ===== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- ===== Tests ===== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Dependencies(main)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Informations du projet -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- ===== Informations Maven ===== -->
<groupId>org.example.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>climb</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>-->
</dependencies>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<!-- ===== Informations générales ===== -->
<name>${projectName}</name>
<url>http://example.org</url>
<description>
    Le super projet de gestion de climbs d'incident et de demandes d'évolution !
</description>

<organization>
    <name>Mon Entreprise</name>
    <url>https://exemple.org</url>
</organization>

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- DistributionManagement -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>site-projet</id>
        <url>scp://localhost/tmp/</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>


<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Propriétés -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<properties>
    <projectName>climb</projectName>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.version>5.0.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <struts.version>2.5.16</struts.version>
</properties>


<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Modules -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<modules>
    <module>climb-webapp</module>
    <module>climb-business</module>
    <module>climb-consumer</module>
    <module>climb-model</module>
    <module>climb-technical</module>
</modules>


<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Gestion des dépendances -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ===== Modules ===== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>climb-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>climb-business</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>climb-consumer</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>climb-model</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>climb-technical</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ===== Bibliothèques tierces ===== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.bval</groupId>
            <artifactId>bval-jsr</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSR-250 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSR-330 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Gestion des logs avec Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-bom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${struts.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Build -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<build>
    <!-- ===== Gestion des plugins ===== -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Packaging JAR -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Compilation des sources Java -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Packaging WAR -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Assemblage -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Site -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <locales>fr</locales>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Gestion des rapports -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <!-- ===== Rapport d'information général sur le projet ===== -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>

        <!-- ===== Rapport sur les tests ===== -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>

                <!-- reportSet d'agrégation des rapports des sous-projets (modules) -->
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>report</report>
                    </reports>
                    <!-- ne pas exécuter ce sous-rapport dans les sous-projets -->
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                    </configuration>
                </reportSet>

                <!-- reportSet non agrégé, exécuté dans tous les sous-projets (modules) -->
                <reportSet>
                    <id>modules</id>
                    <!-- exécuter ce sous-rapport dans les sous-projets -->
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <reports>
                        <report>report</report>
                    </reports>
                    <configuration>
                        <aggregate>false</aggregate>
                    </configuration>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>

        <!-- ===== Génération de la Javadoc ===== -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <quiet>true</quiet>
                <locale>fr</locale>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <!-- reportSet exécuté dans tous les modules -->
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>javadoc</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
                <!-- reportSet d'agrégation des rapports des sous-modules -->
                <reportSet>
                    <id>aggregate</id>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <reports>
                        <report>aggregate</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>

        <!-- ===== Rapport d'analyse du code par Checkstyle ===== -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>src/build/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <!-- reportSet exécuté dans tous les modules -->
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>checkstyle</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
                <!-- reportSet d'agrégation des rapports des sous-modules -->
                <reportSet>
                    <id>checkstyle-aggregate</id>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipExec>true</skipExec>
                    </configuration>
                    <reports>
                        <report>checkstyle-aggregate</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

For the insertion, I use a Classe SpotManager which has @Transactional and refers a DAO class as: ` @Override
    public void updateTopo(Topo topo) {

```
    topoDao.update(topo);
}
```

Then the DAO is:

```
 public void update(Topo) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(o);
}
```

If I update topo.name for example, then no problem, it's written in the Db. However, if I pass the topo.spots then I get no error but nothing written either.

Comment: Altough likely not the problem, you might try to remove the `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` dependency as `hibernate-core:5.3.5` already declares a dependency to `javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2`. For help on the insertion failure it might help to add source code to your question that shows how you try to add entries.

Comment: Thanks @Selaron I removed the hibernate-core as you suggested and updated the edit with my insertion ( / update) code. Any other attribute is updated just fine, only the list going pointing into that Join table is failing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After updating your Hibernate dependency you have an old version of `javax.persistence-api` left on your class path which does not define the method
`javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()`.

Comment: nice one, I downgraded org.hibernate.javax.persistence from 1.0.1.Final to 1.0.0.Final and it removed the compilation error. However, the Db still not updated

Comment: @Rannved which dependencies and versions are you using in your project?

Comment: I have just updated the main description with the dependencies. As explained, the compilation is ok now but remains that the insertion is not working for the join table while working fine for the others. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can join two tables with @JoinColumn annotation within the Entity class.

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private SpotTopoEntity spotTopo;
```

Comment: Thanks, that might work but I need to have some Spots and Topos independantly as not each entity will be linked to the other. Then spot_topo that can connect according to some conditions. With your solution, I understand that the joinTable will be systematically updated for each insertion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, the version had to be **downgraded from 1.0.1.Final to 1.0.0.Final** (that removed the compilation error)@selaron Then the other issue (not inserting) was due to the fact that **I was inserting  spots into the topo object without inserting topos into the spot object**.
I updated my dev accordingly and the insertion into the join table works fine.
Thanks all!